# When does Python create class object in memory?

Tags: python, class, object, memory

Let's take a look of the following example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
```

***My current understanding is when Python interpreter reads the line `class Foo(object)` [Foo class definition], it will create a Foo class object in memory.***

Then I did the following two tests:

```
>>> dir()
['Foo', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

It looks like the Python interpreter has stored 'Foo' class object in memory.

```
>>> id(Foo)
140608157395232
```

It seems Foo class object is at memory address: 140608157395232.

Is my reasoning correct?  If not, when does Python create class object in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What do you mean by "when"?

Comment: I mean when does the Python interpreter create class object?  What is the triggering event of class object creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more specific, Python creates the class type object when it finishes processing the *entire*  class definition (so being pedantic, it wouldn't create it until it had parsed and processed the `pass` line as well, in your example).

This is typically only relevant in esoteric edge cases, like the following:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     print repr(Foo)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in Foo
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

But yes, your reasoning is generally correct.

Comment: Thanks, @Amber.  The example you provided is just to the point!

Comment: Even more specific: after finding the end of the class definition, the class is created by invoking its metaclass, with the default metaclass being `type`.  There is (much) more detail in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The class object is created by the line `class Foo(object):`, yes. It is not created when it reads that line, though, it's created when it reaches the end of the class definition.

The `id` of the class does not need to have any relation to the memory address. That's an implementation detail, and one you don't have any use of.

Comment: Thanks, Lennart.  The Python documentation says CPython's id does indicate memory address. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id.

Comment: @Mingyu: Yeah, but that's CPython.

Comment: Agree... The `id` may or may not be the memory address depends on Python implementation :-)

Answer (score 0):

A class object, rather than an instance is created at read or import time and any static class methods are created at that time.

A class instance is created and `class.__init__()` executed when you assign an object of that class type.

Just to complicate things another class ***may*** have a static member of your class so may create an instance at it's own declare time.

Comment: I think `__init__` is to initialize variables, and `__new__` is to create class instance.

Comment: Also note that assignment has nothing to do with when `__init__` is called. `Foo()` on its own on a line still calls `Foo.__init__`.

Comment: @Mingyu is correct, the `__new__` function creates the instance (in Python2 that's part of why you write `class K(object)`, so as to inherit `object.__new__` if you don't define your own `__new__`; in 3.x the inheriting-from-`object` is implicit), and then its `__init__` function initializes it.  Note that if your `__new__` returns a different object, that's what you get, e.g., `class K(object): def __new__(cls): return 1` (indent properly) and `k = K()` and you'll see that `k` is an ordinary `int` with value 1.